# The repository ''http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb bionic Release'' does not have a Release file

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, updates, repository

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Oracle VM virtual box in my Windows 10 system.

After executing this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this error

```
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Apparently the URL is wrong. If you try to open it in a browser, you get 404 Not found error.

Comment: Use https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/ to find the correct URL

Comment: I am very new  in ubuntu.
@karel, no, I don't find the answers of that question helpful to me. :(

Comment: Looks like you misread the instructions on how to add Google Chrome...or perhaps you unwisely followed poor instructions. Do you have a link to the instructions that you followed? How to fix it is trivial if you know how to use a text editor - do you? This site is poorly suited to step-by-step training.

Comment: @user535733, I can't remember from where I took instructions to add Google chrome. It was a year ago! Since then, I haven't used the virtual box and ubuntu again. And now I wanna use chromium. Yes, I know who to use a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Your source `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` is incorrect.

There should be no reference to `bionic` in the file.

It should read:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

The first two lines are, of course, optional. The important element is using `stable` instead of `bionic`.

Comment: Kindly tell me what command lines I should write to fix the problem, please.

Comment: I actually didn't understand what you meant by text editor in this context. If you meant writing commands on the terminal, then I don't know. :|

Comment: Kindly check this screenshot: https://i.paste.pics/82K4G.png
I just unchecked the selected box. The error is not showing now! Is that action okay?

Comment: Much better. Run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`. If there are no errors, then you have fixed it.

Comment: Yes, no errors appear there now.

Comment: Congratulations!